# Granting function Cross-Tenant Azure RM access

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I can currently manage resources across multiple Azure AD tenants with Azure Resource Manager through PowerShell (client ID 1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2), using delegated permissions with a user account who has elevated privileges in both Azure AD’s and all relevant subscriptions. I.e., a `SubscriptionClient` with logged in with this user has a method `SubscriptionClient.tenants.List()` which will list multiple tenants if I have access to subscriptions in different tenants as this user.

I’m writing cross-tenant automation, and what I’m trying to do is have a .NET function in Azure do the above without delegating it permissions from some sort of cross-tenant God user account (as an old-school service account). Instead, I want to give the function itself the permissions.

1. First attempt - using an MSI:

   I figured to actually get a service principle to exist in a
   non-native tenant of a service principle is to use (newlines for readability):

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Target_foreign_tenant}/adminconsent
       ?client_id={id_of_msi}
       &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
   ```

   Using an admin account and accept the permissions. The issue here is the
   MSI needs Graph API permissions for this to work. So I then tried:

   ```bsh
   New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment `#`
       -ObjectId {object_id_of_msi} `#`
       -PrincipalId {object_id_of_msi} `#`
       -ResourceId {object_id_of_graph_SP} `#`
       -Id {permissions_id_of_relevant_graph_role}
   ```

   The above command, run with global admin permissions for the service principal of an MSI, gives the "insufficient privileges" error shown below. (Note that on the service principal of an app registration, this works fine, no privileges issue.)

   ```
   New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
   Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
   Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
   HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
   HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
   HttpResponseStatus: Completed
   At line:1 char:1
   + New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -Id {where id would be here}
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
   ```

   I was following: [MSI Permissions for Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013011/msi-permissions-for-graph-api)
2. So then I gave up on MSI and decided to use a multi-tenant enabled
   Web app App registration instead. I again used:

   ```
   https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Target_forgien_ADTenant}/adminconsent
       ?client_id={id_of_webappreg}
       &redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
   ```

   With success! I could now see in my foreign tenant my app
   registration under "Enterprise apps", and query in the
   foreign Azure AD tenant and see the service principal – hurrah!

   I then excited assigned my enterprise app owner privileges to a
   subscription in my foreign tenant, and ran my function which lists
   tenants and subscriptions using the API at the top. Unfortunately, it
   can only see subscriptions in its home tenant still, unlike a user.

Any help on how to get either of these approaches working? My function looks like this:

```cs
public static async Task<SubscriptionClient> GetSubscriptionClient(string clientID, string clientSecret, string tenantName)
{
    var serviceCreds = new TokenCredentials(await GetRMAccessToken(clientID, clientSecret, tenantName).ConfigureAwait(false));

    return new SubscriptionClient(serviceCreds);
}

public static async Task<string> GetRMAccessToken(string clientID, string clientSecret, string tenantName)
{
    var authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName;
    var resourceUrl = "https://management.azure.com/";

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
    var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
    var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientCred);
    var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

    return token;
}

var subClient = await SubscriptionManagement.GetSubscriptionClient(clientID, clientSecret, tenantName);
var tenants = new List<string>();
foreach(var tenant in subClient.Tenants.List())
{
    tenants.Add(tenant.TenantId + " - " + tenant.TenantId);                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experence, it seems that we can't get the all of tenants with **application  permission**.

I also test it with multi-tenant enabled Web app App, I also get the same result with you.

I captured that rest API request with fiddler. It sends the [List tanents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list) API.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2016-06-01
```

The rest api is used for getting the tenants for **your account**.

```
Gets the tenants for your account.
```