# Giving an Azure Managed Identity Directory.Read.All

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to give an Azure Managed Identity access to the Graph with Directory.Read.All. I was able to get it to work by following this blog: https://blog.bredvid.no/accessing-apis-using-azure-managed-service-identity-ff7802b887d?gi=f2307752395a, however:

- that throws an Authorization_RequestDenied error (though apparently expected: [MSI Permissions for Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013011/msi-permissions-for-graph-api/48014153#48014153))
- I would prefer to get this working under az-cli

I tried...

```sh
graphId=$(az ad sp list --filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'" --query "[0].objectId")
roleId=$(az ad sp list --filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'" --query "[0].appRoles[?value=='Directory.Read.All' && contains(allowedMemberTypes, 'Application')] | [0].id")
az role assignment create --role $roleId --assignee-object-id fa22d971-c442-41f2-add1-77e636f80d31 --scope $graphId --assignee-principal-type MSI
```

But this results in... "The request did not have a subscription or a valid tenant level resource provider."

I am thinking this means I don't have the scope right. Is it possible to do this assignment under az-cli?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it with AZ CLI. `az role assignment` manages RBAC assignments for Azure Management, not Graph API. You can check my article to see how to do it with Azure AD PowerShell: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to assign a service principal(MSI) to an application role currently, all commands [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest).

The `az role assignment create` is to add the user/service principal/group to the azure resource as an RBAC role, not that you want, it equals the steps in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

---

Besides, if you want to use the azure CLI instead of powershell because of the cross-platform issue. You could try the [powershell core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-6), it is cross-platform, refer to this [link](https://blogs.endjin.com/2019/05/how-to-use-the-azuread-module-in-powershell-core/) to install `AzureAD.Standard.Preview` module in it, then you will be able to use the `AzureAD` commands.