# Grant O365 Management API permissions to a managed identity

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-powershell-v2, o365security-compliance

I'm trying to use an Azure Function to collect the O365 Activity Logs with the O365 Management API.
I would want to do this with the function managed identity, but I currently can't find a way to give the delegated API Permission "Read activity data for your organization" to my managed identity. (neither by using portal or powershell)

Can this be done by using a managed identity, or should I fallback to using a regular appreg with oauth credentials being stored

Comment: thx for this reference, this was very useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add permissions directly to the managed identity as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48014153/132639) post.